# Android EditText number keyboard not popping up upon click

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a ListView which derives from a custom row which I have created. This is all working fine, accept the fact that my EditText refuses to show the number keyboard.

Below is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/chkPlayer" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkPlayer"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chkPlayer"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/started"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:id="@+id/chkStarted" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/captain"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkStarted"
        android:id="@+id/chkCaptain" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/gk"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkCaptain"
        android:id="@+id/chkGK" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtTime"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin10"
        android:hint="@string/time"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chkGK"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkGK" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried several additional approaches however simply cannot get it to work, below is my custom Array Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View rowView = convertView;

    if(rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_squad, parent, false);

        holder = new Holder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        holder.chkPlayer = (CheckBox)rowView.findViewById(R.id.chkPlayer);
        holder.txtTime = (EditText)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);

        rowView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtName.setText(playerNames.get(position));
    holder.chkPlayer.setFocusable(false);
    holder.chkStarted.setFocusable(false);
    holder.chkCaptain.setFocusable(false);
    holder.chkGK.setFocusable(false);
    //holder.txtTime.setFocusable(true);
    //InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    //im.showSoftInput(holder.txtTime, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT));
    //EditText txtTime = (EditText)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);

    return rowView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

Comment: if you dont specify an input type , does the soft keyboard come up ?

Comment: Tried that still nothing